# How can I calculate all irreducible polynomials of 31 degree in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, number-theory, finite-fields

How can I calculate all binary irreducible polynomials of degree 31? or how i calculate all irreducible $f$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$?

(The irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ and $\mathbb R$ are distinguish; for example, in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$, we have $x^2+1=(x+1)(x+1)$.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what good it will be to calculate them, as there are `143.522.117`. See http://oeis.org/search?q=+2%2C+3%2C+5%2C+8%2C+14%2C+23%2C+41%2C+71%2C+127%2C+226&sort=&language=english&go=Search

Comment: Over R none will be irreducible. Over Q would be a different matter. Over Z_2 there will be a large number of them, as @belisarius has already indicated.

Answer (score 5):

This gives you the irreducible polynomials up to order `n - 1` in  $\mathbb Z_2[x]$

```
n = 5; 
Table[Pick @@ Transpose[({#, IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#, Modulus -> 2]} & /@ 
                                       (FromDigits[#, x] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, i]))], 
      {i, n}] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, for degree 31 there are 2^32 == `4,294,967,296` tuples to explore. That's not feasible in this way.

I doubt about the usefulness of calculating them all, but here's a memory-diet way to do that given enough lifespan on your part:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];
s = {};
n = 31;
While[(s = NextSubset[Range[n + 1], s]) != {},
     If[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#, Modulus -> 2], Print@#] &[
                   Array[x^# &, n + 1, 0].SparseArray[Thread[Rule[s, 1]], n + 1]];
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]